# Resize img to the size of the div parent WITHOUT respecting ratio

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I have an img inside a div and I want the image to fit the div without respecting its ratio. I want the image to be stretched to match the div size. For now, the image is just croped to the div size so I can't see it entirely.

Here is my HTML:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div ref="draggableContainer" id="draggable-container" @mousedown="dragMouseDown" :style="taille" >
      <v-img :src="images.caisse" id="boximage"></v-img>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
#draggable-container {
  position: absolute; 
  z-index: 100;
  width: var(--largeur);
  height: var(--longueur);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: var(--longueur);
  transform: rotate(0deg)
}

#boximage{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  resize: both;
}
```

The important thing is that the size of the div is going to change in my project according to the user choices.
Thank you for your help!

---

If someone is trying to resize an image without croping it and uses Vuetify, you need to add "contain" to your :

```
<v-img **contain** :src="images.caisse" id="boximage"></v-img>
```

If you don't, you will forever have your images cut!

Comment: To clarify: you want the image to cover the parent `div` and by that ignoring the aspect ratio of the original image? From what I can tell your code should already do that. I suspect there might be other style rules involved that make it act differently.

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do, but for now the image is cut and not resized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68096179/resize-img-to-the-size-of-the-div-parent-without-respecting-ratio?noredirect=1#comment120356563_68096179), I’d say the code snippet you show us should already be doing what you describe. It could be that something else in your code is causing different behavior. Perhaps there is an `object-fit` set to images, or something?

In any case, when I isolate the HTML and CSS you mention, I get the results I expect, and I think you are also describing. Consider the following snippet:

```css
    :root {
        --largeur: 200px;
        --longueur: 400px;
    }

    #draggable-container {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 100;
        width: var(--largeur);
        height: var(--longueur);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: var(--longueur);
        transform: rotate(0deg)
    }

    #boximage{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: block;
        resize: both;
    }
```

```html
<div id="draggable-container">
    <img id="boximage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In fact, it works but because I use Vuetify, I had to add "contain" to my <v-img> to have the images resized and not croped!